# 'SelectedIndex' : Undeclared identifier in C++

Tags: c++, undeclared-identifier

I'm writing a simple program that references the state of 
SelectedIndex which at any given point can be a number 0 - 9

SelectedIndex is controlled by a dropdownlist.

When I try and reference the state of SelectedIndex:

```
if (SelectedIndex == 0)
{
textBox1->Text = "C Egyptian";
}
```

I'm getting an "undeclared identifier" error upon compiling.

I just want to be able to reference the state SelectedIndex for my conditional.

Any ideas?

Comment: simply it not within that particular scope where you are using it

Comment: `dropdownlist->SelectedIndex`? Just guessing here. [mcve] please.

Comment: private: System::Void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
   {
         if (sender == comboBox1)

    {

        String^ ps = String::Concat(L"New index is ", (Object^)(comboBox1->SelectedIndex).ToString());

        MessageBox::Show(ps, L"Index Change");

    }
   }

Comment: @CyberneticJesus Add such additional information to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm Sorry for the n00b question... I'm very new to C++ but I actually figured it out myself in VS just on a guess.

Problem was I should have been using

```
if (comboBox1->SelectedIndex == 0)
{
textBox1->Text = "C Egyptian";
}
```

instead of

```
if (SelectedIndex == 0)
{
textBox1->Text = "C Egyptian";
}
```

have a good one